# What is cov(X,Y), where X=min(U,V) and Y=max(U,V) for independent Normal(0,1) variables U and V?

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, covariance

Let:

- $U, V \overset{i.i.d.}{\sim} \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, i.e. independent standard Normal random variables.
- $X=\min(U,V)$
- $Y=\max(U,V)$

What is the covariance of $X$ and $Y$?

---

Related: [What is cov(X,Y), where X=min(U,V) and Y=max(U,V) for independent *uniform*(0,1) variables U and V?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/25965/12359)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$\newcommand{\E}{\mathrm{E}}$ $\newcommand{\Var}{\mathrm{Var}}$ $\newcommand{\cov}{\mathrm{Cov}}$ $\newcommand{\Expect}{{\rm I\kern-.3em E}}$

As a direct consequence of the definition of covariance, $\cov (X,Y)= \E(XY)-\E(X)\E(Y)$.

Fact 1:
$U, V \overset{i.i.d.}{\sim} \mathcal{N}(0,1)$
$\Rightarrow  U - V \sim \mathcal{N}(0,2)$  ([sum of normally distributed random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables&oldid=755961660#Independent_random_variables))
$ \Rightarrow |U - V|$ is a [half-normal random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Half-normal_distribution&oldid=754001398) with parameter $\sigma = \sqrt2$
$ \Rightarrow \E (|U - V|) = \frac{\sigma\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi}} = \frac{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi}} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}$

Fact 2:
$\E(X)+\E(Y) = \E(X+Y)$ ([linearity of the expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Expected_value&oldid=756486874#Linearity)).
We have $\E(X+Y) = \E (\min(U,V)+\max(U,V))= \E(U+V) = \E(U)+\E (V) = 0 + 0 = 0$. As a result,  $\E(Y) = -\E(X)$.

Fact 3:
Since $Y-X = |U - V|$:
$2\E(Y) = \E(Y)-\E(X) = \E(Y-X) = \E (|U - V|)= \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}$, hence $\E(Y)= \frac{2}{2\sqrt{\pi}}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}$

Fact 4:
Since $XY=UV$, we have $\E(XY)=\E(UV)=\E (U)\E (V)=0$

Using these facts: $\cov (X,Y)= \E(XY)-\E(X)\E(Y)= 0 + \E(Y)\E(Y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}=\frac{1}{\pi}$.

Comment: Should have a negative sign for $cov (X,Y) $ - you've used $E(Y)^2$ instead of $E (X)E (Y) $ in fact 4.  Good answer though.

Comment: E(X)E(Y) would be the same as E^2(Y).  The problem is that the sign changed from - to +.  It is a shame to give such a nice proof and make one careless mistake at the very end.  I overlooked it at first glance.

Comment: The sign changed as $\E(X) = -\E(Y)$ (fact 2). I posted the answer as I thought readers from [What is cov(X,Y), where X=min(U,V) and Y=max(U,V) for independent uniform(0,1) variables U and V?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/25965/12359) could be interested.

Comment: Sorry Franck somehow I got confused.  it looks like you had it right and we had it wrong.